# Duplicate Python Installs

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, python

I was not aware that Ubuntu 14.04 already comes pre-installed with Python. However, I'm not sure if it's installed with Python 2 or 3. Either way, I went to the Python website, downloaded the package for Python 2.7, unzipped it and installed it manually using the `make` command.

I'm a little concerned that I have two installations of the same thing on my PC. Will this cause a major issue and/or should I be concerned of this? What is the easiest way for me to determine if Python 2.7 was already included in the initial Ubuntu installation?

If this is something I should worry about, what is the best way to uninstall the redundant version of Python?

Answer (score 1):

Check your pre-installed or available Python packages with `apt-cache policy …`

*Examples:*

```
% apt-cache policy python 
python:
  Installed: 2.7.9-1
  Candidate: 2.7.9-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.9-1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

% apt-cache policy python3
python3:
  Installed: 3.4.3-1
  Candidate: 3.4.3-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.4.3-1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

---

To remove your manually `make install` installed Python interpreter, follow the steps below.

1. First try `make uninstall` in your unzipped source folder. If that works, than stop here.

**If not, follow the next steps**

2. Download and unzip the archive again
3. Start the usual compilation steps again **without** `make install`

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   ```
4. Install `checkinstall`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   ```
5. Install `python` again with `checklinstall`, yes, I'm sure. **;)**

   ```
   sudo checkinstall
   ```

   `checkinstall` creates a deb package that can be easily removed.
6. After that, you will see a message like *To remove the package use …*, do that.

Comment: So when I run `apt-cache policy python`, I get nearly the same output as you do:


`python:
  Installed: 2.7.5-5ubuntu3
  Candidate: 2.7.5-5ubuntu3`
  
If I were to have had two installations of Python, would I see duplicates entries using `apt-cache`?

Comment: No, you see one (pre-)installed python, version 2.7.5, installed by your [apt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) system.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the following command,

```
sudo find / -type f -executable -iname 'python*' -exec file -i '{}' \; | awk -F: '/x-executable; charset=binary/ {print $1}' | xargs readlink -f | sort -u | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo -n "%: "; % -V'
```

You will get output as list of python versions you have in your system.

For Example I have shown my system output below,

```
arul@arul-pc ~ $  sudo find / -type f -executable -iname 'python*' -exec file -i '{}' \; | awk -F: '/x-executable; charset=binary/ {print $1}' | xargs readlink -f | sort -u | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo -n "%: "; % -V'
[sudo] password for arul: 
/usr/bin/python2.7: Python 2.7.6
/usr/bin/python3.4: Python 3.4.0
/usr/bin/python3.4m: Python 3.4.0
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me :/ I entered the full list of commands and my PC stalls. .  . 

I thought that it may be because I might not have one of the programs installed that you're using (I'll be honest, I don't follow the list of commands that well), but I'd imagine Ubuntu would raise a warning in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14 comes with both Python versions 2 and 3

If you want to use Python 3 just open Terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type: `python3` and you will get prompted to run Python 3 on the shell:

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Jun 19 2015, 14:20:21) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Type `exit()` when you finish.

. If you prefer Python 2 instead then just type `python` and you will be able to use it via shell:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Type `exit()` when you finish.